# How to find maximum, latest and average profit in sql

Tags: sql, date, max, aggregates

I have a table where i have user_id, item_id , profit_date and profit as a column. what i want is avg profit, maximum profit and latest profit for each user and item. i am able to find max and avg but stuck in finding latest profit because for this i have to use date column. latest profit here means profit on latest date.

i have tried using aggregation but stuck in latest part. either i have to find this latest profit separately and then again join to this table where max and avg profit is found , and joining should be like 1 to 1.

-- Table script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample (
    `user_id` INT,
    `item_id` INT,
    `profit_date` DATETIME,
    `profit` INT
);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES
    (1,10,'2022-01-01 00:00:00',10),
    (1,10,'2022-01-02 00:00:00',30),
    (1,10,'2022-01-03 00:00:00',20),
    (1,15,'2022-01-04 00:00:00',10),
    (1,15,'2022-01-05 00:00:00',15),
    (1,15,'2022-01-06 00:00:00',20),
    (2,10,'2022-01-07 00:00:00',10),
    (2,10,'2022-01-08 00:00:00',30),
    (2,10,'2022-01-09 00:00:00',20),
    (2,15,'2022-01-10 00:00:00',10),
    (2,15,'2022-01-11 00:00:00',10),
    (2,15,'2022-01-12 00:00:00',7);
```

--sample input table

| user_id | item_id | profit_date | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 01-01-2022 | 10 |
| 1 | 10 | 02-01-2022 | 30 |
| 1 | 10 | 03-01-2022 | 20 |
| 1 | 15 | 04-01-2022 | 10 |
| 1 | 15 | 05-01-2022 | 15 |
| 1 | 15 | 06-01-2022 | 20 |
| 2 | 10 | 07-01-2022 | 10 |
| 2 | 10 | 08-01-2022 | 30 |
| 2 | 10 | 09-01-2022 | 20 |
| 2 | 15 | 10-01-2022 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 | 11-01-2022 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 | 12-01-2022 | 7 |

-- expected output

| user_id | item_id | max_profit | avg_profit | latest_profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 30 | 20 | 20 |
| 1 | 15 | 20 | 15 | 20 |
| 2 | 10 | 30 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 15 | 10 | 9 | 7 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine aggregation with a windowed expression to find the most recent value:

```
with lp as (
  select *,
    First_Value(profit) over(partition by user_id, item_id order by profit_date desc) lp
  from t
)
select user_id, item_id, 
  Max(profit) max_profit,
  Avg(profit) avg_profit,
  Max(lp) latest_profit
from lp
group by user_id, item_id;
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9gmkn0cq)